# Two cards are drawn at random from a normal deck of cards.

Tags: probability

I was wondering how to do this question.
"Two cards are drawn at random from a normal deck of cards.What is the probability that the second card is
 a two if the first card was a two?"
And how do i do questions similar to this?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by observing that after drawing a two you're left with a deck of $51$ cards of which 3 are twos. The probability is therefore $3/51 = 1/17$.

The more elaborate solution is to use the definition of conditional probability calculate the probability that you pick $2$ twos (which is $6/1326=1/221$) and divide that by the probability that the first you pick is a two which is $4/52=1/13$. The qutient is $13/221=1/17$

Comment: Thank you.It seems i was overthinking this one a bit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

There are $51$ equiprobable candidates for the second card (all cards except the first one). Among these candidates there are $3$ two's.

P.S. The question: "What is the probability that the first card (taken blindly) is a two if the second card appears to be a two?" is often experienced as "more difficult" but can be handled just the same way.

Comment: Yea, the way it was worded did make it pretty harder in my opinion.Thank you for your help.